# Import and export datetime object

Tags: export, import, date-and-time

I have a list of datetime objects and numbers, say

[image]

When I export to a txt file, it gives

> {DateObject[{2017, 1, 1, 0, 0}, "Minute", "Gregorian", 0., {"ISODateTime"}], 0}
>
> {DateObject[{2017, 1, 1, 0, 1}, "Minute", "Gregorian", 0., {"ISODateTime"}], 1}
>
> {DateObject[{2017, 1, 1, 0, 2}, "Minute", "Gregorian", 0., {"ISODateTime"}], 0}
>
> {DateObject[{2017, 1, 1, 0, 3}, "Minute", "Gregorian", 0., {"ISODateTime"}], 0}

Is there any easy way to import the txt file and get back the datetime object?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide your data file otherwise, you can also check  this  link: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/352992

Comment: `ReadList @ file.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably easier to save as a .csv but you can do it with a .txt as follows:

```
 dateObject = {DateObject[{2017, 1, 1, 0, 0}, "Minute", 
   "Gregorian", 0., {"ISODateTime"}], 
  DateObject[{2017, 1, 1, 0, 1}, "Minute", "Gregorian", 
   0., {"ISODateTime"}], 
  DateObject[{2017, 1, 1, 0, 2}, "Minute", "Gregorian", 
   0., {"ISODateTime"}], 
  DateObject[{2017, 1, 1, 0, 3}, "Minute", "Gregorian", 
   0., {"ISODateTime"}]}

 Export["C:\\Users\\Sarahs\\Desktop\\FileOutput.txt", dateObject];
 input = Import["C:\\Users\\Sarahs\\Desktop\\FileOutput.txt"];
```

At this point, input is a string with "\n" marking the new lines, so you need to split it up.

```
split = StringSplit[input, "\n"]
```

Now you have a bunch of strings so you just need to convert them to an expression.

```
ToExpression /@ split
```